# Kestrel returns HTTP 500 when it runs as an exe

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a small Asp.Net Core web app. I targeted the net461 framework because it has a dependency on Restsharp.

When I run this web app as ./web.exe, it returns with HTTP 500.
When I run with "dotnet run" from project folder, it runs fine.

I must use the first version because I publish that to a provider who doesn't have .Net SDK.

What can i do?

My `project.json` is here:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    //"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    //    "version": "1.0.0",
    //    "type": "platform"
    //  },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "RestSharp": "105.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8","net451"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
    //"netcoreapp1.0": {
    //  "imports": [
    //    "dotnet5.6",
    //    "portable-net45+win8"
    //  ]
    //}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win81-x64": {}
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. I missed something from WebhostBuilder.
With 
`.UseIISIntegration()`
 it works fine.